# Starter problem with 1994 Honda Accord

Tags: honda, starting, accord, starter

so, when I turn the key to start position on the Accord (EX) no sound is made.  You can push start it, and the battery is fine - lights, horn, everything.  But there is absolutely no noise.

I'm thinking it's either the solenoid or the starter.  Leaning toward the solenoid, as I think if it was the starter you'd at least hear a click.

ALSO: you can push start the car and run it fine.

My question: How can I trouble-shoot which it is?  I see the cable coming from the (+) on the battery to the starter, and also a wire going to a wiring block above it.  I'm thinking the solenoid is built on to the side of the starter, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, yes the starter solenoid is attached to the starter motor. And yes from your description it sure sounds like a problem starter.

Are you doing this work yourself, or having it done?

First have you checked ALL fuses and relays in the system? Do that first. There is likely two different fuse boxes to contend with, one inside the passenger compartment and one inside the engine compartment. Check your owners manual for the location of the fuses & relays for the starter system.

If those are okay, removing the starter is as easy as:

1. Remove ground strap at the battery (ENSURE IT WON'T FALL BACK ON BATTERY!)
2. disconnect electrical leads from the starter
3. disconnect three bolts that hold starter to bell housing.
4. remove the starter.

That's a pretty easy job depending on your ground clearance. Test the starter on the bench.

Comment: I will do this myself.  I was more wondering how to trouble shoot whether the problem is the solendoid, starter, or power to it.  Obviously the main cable from battery (+) is good (though I'll check).  How many wires go from the chassis to the solenoid?  How should I check the voltmeter to test it?  Thanks.  I do plan to do it myself, replaced starters before but just want to isolate the problem.

Comment: You have 2 wires going to the starter - One huge red wire directly to the battery and a 'signal' wire that goes to your ignition switch.  The large wire should always have power.  The small wire should have power when you turn the key to start.  Same for any relays in the starting circuit.